# Spring Boot / Hibernate - How to turn on entity validation output?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am getting this error on Spring Boot:

```
2018-03-13 13:39:26.663  WARN 6980 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

I know it's a error on the ORM. But I want to know which one. I have many entities. Probably one mapping is wrong. Which one?

Edit - Current logback.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration packagingData="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%ex{full, DISPLAY_EX_EVAL}
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Edit2:

Tried to downgrade logback on .pom

```
<properties>
    <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
</properties>
```

No luck. Does not seem an issue with logback.

Comment: To know the reason of this error, you need to read the complete stack trace of the exception. But you chose not to post it, thus shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: It does not output it. That's the problem..

Comment: You need to set the log level of org.hibernate package to debug - depends on your logging configuration. Are you using logback? You can try putting 'logging.level.org.hibernate=debug' in your application.properties

Comment: I am using logback. setting logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG outputted a lot, except the exception.

Comment: So the exception is not coming from that package. can you try org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure=debug

Comment: I have set the root logging to debug with no luck. Something is preventing the nested exception from being printed, I guess. I am using spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE.

Comment: can you then try and pass the --debug option when you start your application?

Comment: No luck with --debug. According to logback documentation https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html As of version 1.1.4 stack traces are disabled by default. Will have to find out how to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [logback's documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ex) "%ex" should be used to output full stacktraces. Configuration should be similar to:

```
 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%msg%n%ex{full, DISPLAY_EX_EVAL}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```

Comment: tried it, no luck.. seems hibernate is not sending the exception

Comment: @ThiagoSayão - have you tried adding the org.hibernate package to logback config or just move to older logback version if you think the issue is in logback?

Comment: I have set the root to debug, so It should work. Also tried to downgrade logback. Does not seem an issue with logback.

Comment: Thru Intellij Idea run dashboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166770/discussion-between-hovanessyan-and-thiago-sayao).

Comment: No success with command line, still does not output the exception stack trace.